# How to listen for a "particular" animation-end on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I listen for a particular animationend when multiple animations are triggered on an element. In my case, I designed an overlay song list (containing li's which when hovered over will trigger an animation) which would pop up when list icon is clicked. The issue is not however brining the menu but closing it. I made a chevron down icon in the overlay song list which would technically slide it down but in my case it shows an abrupt behaviour. I inspected and discovered that some previous animations that were defined on "i" tag and "li" were causing it to misbehave (particularly due to animation end on "i" and "li" tag and the chevron down icon simultaneously). I wonder if I can listen for a particular animation end on chevron down rather than many animations triggered on the general "i" and "li" tag. P.S I'm sorry if that's a little clumsy.

```
      button.list.on("click", function() {

        $("#overlay").css("display", "block");

        $("#overlay").toggleClass("magictime slideDownReturn");
        $("#overlay").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(e) {

              $("#overlay").removeClass("magictime slideDownReturn");
              // $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
        });
  });

      $("#chevronDownIcon").on("click", function() {

        $("#overlay").toggleClass("animated bounceOutDown");

        $("#overlay").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function() {
              console.log("Chevron Animation Ended");
              $("#overlay").removeClass("animated bounceOutDown");
              // $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
        });
  });
// Animate icons and image
  $("i").on("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("animated pulse");
        $(this).on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("animated pulse");
        });
  });

  $("i").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Inside i");
        $("img").toggleClass("animated pulse");
        $("#headphones").toggleClass("animated pulse");
        $("#headphones").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
          $(this).removeClass("animated pulse");
          $("img").removeClass("animated pulse");
        });
        $(this).toggleClass("animated zoomIn");
        $(this).on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
          $(this).removeClass("animated zoomIn");
        });
  });[enter image description here][1]
// Toggle animation on song list item
  $("li").on("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).css("color", "black");
        $(this).toggleClass("animated pulse");
        $(this).on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("animated pulse");
        });
  });
  $("li").on("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).css("color", "white");
  });
```

[image: List Icon]

Answer (score 4):

**Experimental technology**: Referring to [animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend#Properties) and [animationName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent/animationName) on MDN there is an event property named `animationName`. So you can check for the CSS animation name like:

```
$("#headphones").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(event){
   if (event.animationName !== 'example') {
       return;
   }
   $(this).removeClass("animated pulse");
   $("img").removeClass("animated pulse");
});
```

Edit: The good news: since 2020 it is now supported in every major browser. The bad news: its still an experimental technology. See [Can I Use animationName](https://caniuse.com/?search=animationName).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I kinda did a workaround using setTimeout() to accomplish it and now its working for me. But i really appreciate your answer.

Comment: You should give `animationName` a try, because `setTimeout()` isn't very stable from browser to browser.

Comment: on chrome I have to refer to event.originalEvent.animationName, don't know if it's browser specific or just my context.

Comment: Unfortunately its experimental technology. I updated my answer.